# firestore security rules get value of dynamic key?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

document structure:

```
{
    [id 1] {
        field1: "value",
        field2: "value",
        field3: "value"
    }
    [id 2] {
        field1: "value",
        field2: "value",
        field3: "value"
    }
    [id 3] {
        field1: "value",
        field2: "value",
        field3: "value"
    }
}
```

the map ids reference documents and cannot be hardcoded, but field names (field1, field2...), are the same in each map

is there a way to check that only 1 field in any 1 map is changed, and allow write if those conditions are met?

Comment: You can't get a value from a field if you don't know the field's name.  What's your goal here?  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @DougStevenson the document in question contains maps referenced by random ids. I need to only allow 1 sub value in 1 of the maps to be changed. Since only 1 map can be changed, then ```changedKeys()``` only contains 1 item, so one way to get the id of the changed map would be to get the value of the id in the set returned from ```changedKeys()```, but i haven't found any documentation on how to do this. So is there either a way to get the values from a ```Set```, or get the changed map?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're doing from that block of text, but I think that having random field names is working against you here. Not sure if what you're doing is possible.  That's not really a great way to model data in Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson i clarified the question a bit, could you take another look?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One trick you can use in order to keep all the validation logic within Firestore, is adding redundancy to your write requests. For example, you can send the following data from the client:

```js
firestore.collection('A').doc('B').update({ 
  'your_id_here': { 
    field1: 'my new value',

    // keep old data, since we are updating a nested object
    field2: 'original value', 
    field3: 'original value'
  },
  
  // this is the redundancy component
  meta: { id: 'your_id_here' }
});
```

Then, in your Firestore rules you can define your write rule as follows:

```js
function valid() {

  // grab ID from "redundant" part of the request
  let metaID = request.resource.data.meta.id;

  // grab changed keys in the root of the document
  let rootAftectedKeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys(); 

  // validate root keys; need to include "meta", since it is now also part of the object
  let rootChangesGood = rootAffectedKeys.hasOnly([metaID, 'meta']);
  
  // grab the nested object in question             
  let nestedObjectChanges = request.resource.data[metaID].diff(resource.data[metaID]).affectedKeys();

  // check there was only one affected key
  let nestedObjectChangesGood = nestedObjectChanges.size() == 1;

  return rootChangesGood && nestedObjectChangesGood;
}
allow write: if valid();
```

As you can see, I am using `metaID` variable to dynamically access the key of the object.

The advantage of this approach is that (1) all validation logic is within Firebase and (2) it will be much faster than executing a cloud function (since you are only communicating with Firestore directly).

The downside of this approach, however, is that you will have this `meta` object floating around for everyone to see. On top of that, I would add more validations to ensure that `meta` object itself has only required data in the right format. I highly recommend thoroughly testing all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Security rules are not flexible enough to do what you're asking.  This requires looping and assignment, both of which are not available in the language.  I suggest instead using a backend to collect the data from the client, then check to see if it's valid.

Comment: thanks, but also, is there a way to convert a set into a list or get an ttem from a set, and if not, could these features be added in the forseeable future?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: On Stack Overfow, it's conventional to upvote answers that are helpful, and accept them as correct.